# RESTful MVC application

Tags: php, model-view-controller, rest

I'm writing my first MVC web application and I'm trying to keep it as textbook and RESTful as possible.

It's basically a customer ordering system. I have the following urls routing to the following controllers methods

url - controller - method

/customers customer-controller index (shows a list of all customers)

/customers/1 customer-controller view (shows the details of the customer with id = 1)

/orders order-controller index (shows a list of all orders)

/orders/1 order-controller view (shows the details of the order with order_no = 1)

what i want to do is to add a page that shows a list of the orders associated with a specific customer at the url: /customers/1/orders. What i'm not sure is which controller this should map to and to what method.

Should it go in the customers controller, in the order controller or should there be a new customer-orders controller?

Any help, advice, comments much appreciated,

thanks

jim

Comment: You are actually showing a denormalized data view. The ideal would be displaying the data based on the customer, so it's customers/detail/1 which is a method belonging to the customer with order details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see it, you are just applying a filter to the list off all orders. And for this reason it would make more sense to use `Orders` controller.

Also, you might rethink your routing policy. IMHO, it would be better to have something like this: `/:controller((/:action)/:id)`, with default value `index` or `list` for the action. Here are view examples in this pattern:

```
/orders               << all of the orders
/orders/customer/2    << data for customer_id = 2
/orders/locations     << orders , ordered by location
/orders/customer      << orders , ordered by customer
/customers            << all curomers
/order/details/1      << info for single order with id = 1
```

It might be good for you to investigate how Kohana3 does the routing. For all its problems, routing is one of best feature the have.

Well .. just my two cents.